# Bootstrap .container element with inadequately huge margins

Tags: containers, margins

I use bootstrap in my app and encounter a huge problem now. The problem is that `.container` element has left and right margins of 274px on a screen of 1360 px which is quite huge. As a result, everything looks squeezed to the center. This problem is not present on some pages while appears on others without any (clear for me) reason. Here a piece of my code for a section with  `.container` element.

```
<section id="rooms">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 images">
            <div class="img-container">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/rooms/family_one_bedroom.jpg"  class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="captions">
                        <div class="well">
                            <h3>Family One-Bedroom Executive Suite</h3>
                            <hr>
                            <p>On of the best options for families with children</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 images">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/rooms/three_bedroom_grand_suite.jpg"  class="img-responsive">
                <div class="captions">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h3>Three Bedroom Grand Suite</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>A huge option with amazing cityscape view</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 images">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/rooms/family_one_bedroom.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="captions">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h3>Three Bedroom Grand Suite</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>Exquisite Interior And Modern Design</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 images">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/rooms/one_bedroom_garden.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="captions">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h3>One Bedroom Room With Garden View</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>A budget option for backpackers</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 images">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/rooms/delux.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                <div class="captions">
                    <div class="well">
                        <h3>Delux Room With Seaview</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>A luxury option with spectacular view of the coastline</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to set margins of `.container` to 0 in the following way:

```
.container {
   margin: 0!important;
}
```

but it just gave me 0 on the left and huge double margin on the right

How can I solve this problem and get normal margins on both sides?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following.

```
.container {
   margin: 0 auto!important;
   width:95% !important;
}
```

Comment: it has had not impact unfortunatelly

Comment: @Kirill Did you tried adding width also for the container. I have updated that in my code. You can vary the width.

Comment: but if I set up width It will lose responsiveness

Comment: @Kirill if you set with in percentage it won't affect responsiveness

Answer (score 2):

This fills the page nicely...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
</div
```

Comment: I'd go with this suggestion over the suggestion to override the container class's max-width. If all you're looking for is a container that doesn't enforce crazy-narrow (in some/many cases) margins, just use container-fluid.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the `_grid.scss` puts a `max-width` which overrides `width`. Making `max-width 100%` will get rid of any excess margin.

```
.container {
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
```